# Writing SELECT query to combine results from one table on top of another

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with structure as:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_first
{
    Name VARCHAR(30),
    Address VARCHAR(30),
    ID INT
};

CREATE TABLE tb_second
{
    Organisation VARCHAR(30),
    Organisation_Address VARCHAR(30),
    Organisation_ID INT
};
```

I need to run a query that selects data from ID column of table `tb_first` and Organisation_ID column of table `tb_second` and puts them in a single column named as Identity.

tb_first:

```
                        ------------------------------------------------------
                        |      Name   |      Address       |      ID         |
                        ------------------------------------------------------
                        |      John   |  Witham Hall       |      201        |
                        ......................................................
                        |      Harris |  Williams Hall     |      203        |
                        ------------------------------------------------------
```

tb_second:

```
                        ------------------------------------------------------
                        |      Name   |      Address       |      ID         |
                        ------------------------------------------------------
                        | Ample Steels| Maureen Brown      |     1201        |
                        ......................................................
                        |John's Sweets| Oklahoma City      |     1203        |
                        ------------------------------------------------------
```

The select query must return results as:

```
                        ------------------------------------------------------
                        |      Name   |      Address       |   Identity      |
                        ------------------------------------------------------
                        | Ample Steels| Maureen Brown      |     1201        |
                        ......................................................
                        |John's Sweets| Oklahoma City      |     1203        |
                        .....................................................
                        |      John   |  Witham Hall       |      201        |
                        ......................................................
                        |      Harris |  Williams Hall     |      203        |
                        ------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: and what is the question here?

Comment: That can be done with a simple UNION. Btw., you should think about whether this does actually _need_ two tables – if the columns are identical in number and meaning, one single table with an additional attribute for `person` or `organization` could be the better way to go.

Comment: where is your select statement? what have you tried do far?

Comment: Just use `union` along with the select statement

Comment: You haven't even attempted?

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
SELECT Name,Address,ID as Identity FROM tb_first
UNION 
SELECT Organisation,Organisation_address,ID  FROM tb_second
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query :

```
select * from tb_first
union all
select * from tb_second;
```

check the fiddle :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7967d/1

Answer (score 0):

This query is working in my xampp without union. Try it

```
select * from `tb_first`,`tb_second`
```